# jquery modal form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

i try to do a jquery modal form. the problem is, i include myform.php into the jquery's DIV.
the reason why i put myform.php into jquery's div because i want the php do some input validation/checking exiting data in the database instead of using jquery validation. everything works fine. But the problem is, after i save the data, and the modal was close, then i try refresh the page. then i will get some message saying that "Retry to submit.. blabla..bla..bla..." how to avoid this message? or is there any way to integrate php form with PHP??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and not submit the form and send the $_POST data through [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) .

Answer (score 0):

i think the new page added to current page div element
may be you should clear the content of div element after closing dialog